# pandas merge_asof keys must be sorted error after sorting

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I would like to merge a target column from one data frame to another. The merged data frame has many more keys and they are are close, but do not exactly match the original data frame. See an example below:

Original data frame (FDMA)

```
DMA 
130506  
130510  
130512  
130555  
130556
```

Merged data frame (ZC)

```
DMA        Distance (Miles)
1305060    303.87
1305061    305.35
1305062    278.80
1305065    299.94
1305067    291.83

pd.merge_asof(FDMA,ZC[['DMA','Distance (Miles)']],on='DMA')
```

This is what I am expecting

```
DMA     Distance (Miles)
130506  303.87
130510  291.83
130512  XXX
130555  XXX
130556  XXX
```

I have tried the above code and get a ValueError: right keys must be sorted error. I have sorted the values and reset the indexes, but still get the error. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `pd.merge_asof(FDMA,ZC[['DMA','Distance (Miles)']].sort_values('DMA'),on='DMA')`

Comment: Thank you very much Scott! That worked. Can you please tell me how that is different than sorting each data frame before trying merge_asof?

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be different, I just wanted to be clear that you were sorted on your join keys an not the indexes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With the error code "ValueError: right keys must be sorted", the most effective solution is to add `sort_values` in the merge on the keys column:

```
pd.merge_asof(FDMA,ZC[['DMA','Distance (Miles)']].sort_values('DMA'),on='DMA')
```

This ensures that the dataframe is sorted on the join keys as required by `pd.merge_asof`.

Comment: Sorry for the immediate follow up, but I noticed some values are not correct. Anytime the merged value has an extra digit, it doesn't work. Ex. 130506 will merge the value associated to 130510 vs 1305060. Is there an easy way around this or should this be another question?

Comment: Hrm... not sure i competely understand, but merge_asof joins on intergers, floats or datetime, therefore an extra digit is very far away on the number line.  Can you trim the extra digit?

Answer (score 4):

Also, when you have NA in your `on` column, pandas will trow the same error, so before merging you should use `df.dropna()` to solve that.